# Fill in data from database in multiple divs via ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 divs on my html page.
 When I press my button I want to fill the div #question1 with the question1 data from my database and the #question2 div with the question2 data from my database. Now the 2 divs are filled with the same data.

This is my html and js code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    $('#button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getquestions.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#question1').html(data);
                $('#question2').html(data);
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Load" />

<div id="question1"></div>
<div id="question2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The php file

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "mobiledatabase");
$query = "SELECT question1, question2 FROM adult_questions WHERE id=3"; 
$query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$query_row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run); 

if ($query_row==1) { 
     foreach ($query_run as $row ) {
          echo $question1 = $row['question1'];
          echo $question2 = $row['question2'];
        } 
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In PHP pass it like,

```
$question1='';$question2='';
if ($query_row==1) {
    foreach ($query_run as $row ) {
      $question1 = $row['question1'];
      $question2 = $row['question2'];
    } 
}   

echo json_encode(array('question1'=>$question1,'question2'=>$question2));
```

In Jquery,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getquestions.php',dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#question1').html(data.question1);
        $('#question2').html(data.question2);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works when I use the foreach statement instead of your $row = $query_run[0]; Thanks!!

Comment: Try my updated answer, it will work in case when your result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Update your php file.
Create an array like `$retArr = array("question1" =>$question1,"question2" =>$question2);` in your php file Then convert it in to json using `json_encode($retArr)` & `echo json_encode($retArr)` In your ajax response show `$('#question1').html(data.question1);`

Hope this will help